# Problem with encoding in shell script

Tags: command-line, xmllint

I have the following code:

```
#!/bin/bash
task=$1
xml=$(curl -sL "http://login:pass@server.com/issues/$task.xml")
id=$(xmllint --xpath '//issue/id/text()' --format - <<<"$xml")
name=$(xmllint --xpath '//issue/subject/text()' --encode utf8 - <<<"$xml")

echo "task #$id - $name"
```

But when I run it I get encoded cyrillic text like this:

```
task #10014 - &#x41B;&#x438;&#x447;&#x43D;&#x44B;&#x439; &#x43D;&#x43E;&#x43C;&#x435;&#x440; &#x43A;&#x43B;&#x438;&#x435;&#x43D;&#x442;&#x430;
```

Please help to fix it. I don't want this text encoded

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After a few minutes of fighting with `xmllint`, I usually give up and end up using `xmlstarlet` instead which is usually more inclined to doing what you expect it to do. Here:

```
xmlstarlet sel -t -v '//issue/subject' <<< "$xml"
```

<sup>(or <rant>give up altogether on XML and use a more sensible format</rant>).</sup>